# Statement declaration using variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this situation:

```
jsvars['delete'] = "Delete";



$.modal({
        content: $("#delete").html(),
        title: jsvars['delete_category'],
        buttons: {
            jsvars['delete']: function(win) {
                // Do something
            },
            Cancel: function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
        }
    });
```

This prints an error, the code doesn't allow the `jsvars['delete']` to be there when declaring buttons. I tried eval and lots of tricks, but I just don't have any idea how to get that working. I tried googling also, but i am not sure of the terms how to search.

So how can I allow it to use variables there? I need to use the jsvars-array, because I keep translations there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make sure the variable gets named at runtime or it wont work.

this should do it.

```
jsvars['delete'] = "Delete";

buttonObj = {};
buttonObj[jsvars['delete']] = function(win) { // Do something };
buttonObj.cancel = function(win) { win.closeModal(); }


$.modal({
   content: $("#delete").html(),
   title: jsvars['delete_category'],
   buttons: buttonObj
});
```

Comment: @Ris if it solve the problem/question please Accept that answer. :)

Comment: @Shadow Can't yet, have to wait 3 minutes :)

Comment: @Ris you mean you have to wait 15 minutes before you can accept answer? Didn't know that, sorry! :-Z